# Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: password-recovery

Cannot log in to the MySQL server they say mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'Stephen Ankoh'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: log on as root and change the users privleges, when you don't know the root password do something like this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

Login as root and grant access privileges to user
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'yourusername'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'yourusername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
restart mysql /mariadb service.

it will grant user with local as well as remote host(if you want).